# Parenthesis for anonymous JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

Are they the same?

```
var multiply = function () {
      //..
      }();

var multiply1 = (function () {
      //..
      }());
```

Comment: johnny - note that `(function() { })()` and `function() {}()` can be different depending on the context - if not assigned to a variable, the latter will be interpreted as a statement (and a syntax error) rather than an expression.

Comment: Some people prefer `(function(){}())` over `(function(){})()` - just a matter of taste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are totally identical.

Answer (score 9):

As mquander said in that case they are the same, but if you want to read a little more about it you can go to: [An Important Pair of Parens.](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens)

Comment: I like this answer, agree with the article, and now I will start writing my function invocations with parens around them.  Thanks!

Comment: ...and also the same as `(function () {...})()`, which I prefer.

Answer (score 2):

They seem to work the same here in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/G5DZp/