# What is the difference between two declarations of module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, module, iife

What is the different between two declarations of a module in JavaScript?
One has parentheses around the function and other one doesn't?

One article says that

> Notice the () around the anonymous function.  This is required by the
>   language, since statements that begin with the token function are
>   always considered to be function declarations. Including () creates a
>   function expression instead.

Both seem to do the same thing when checked.

```
var person = (function () {
    // Private
    var name = "Robert";
    return {
        getName: function() {
            return name;
        },
        setName: function(newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    };
}());
```

```
var person = function () {
    // Private
    var name = "Robert";
    return {
        getName: function() {
            return name;
        },
        setName: function(newName) {
            name = newName;
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: Neither are [function declarations](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), both are function expressions.

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: usually the second one needs to be instantiated via `person()` first but maybe there is a bug in your runtime environment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parenthesis for anonymous JavaScript functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635942/parenthesis-for-anonymous-javascript-functions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are of two types in JavaScript - declarations and expressions.

This is the difference between the two:

1. Function declarations are hoisted. This means you can call the function before it appears in the program as declarations in JavaScript are **hoisted**.
2. Function expressions can be invoked immediately. A function declaration cannot. This is because expressions **express** (or return a value). Function expressions express a function.

**An example of a function declaration:**

```
foo("bar");

function foo(bar) {
    alert("foo" + bar);
}
```

The above program will work because `foo` is a function declaration.

```
foo("bar"); // throws an error, foo is undefined - not a function

var foo = function (bar) {
    alert("foo" + bar);
};
```

The above program will not work as `foo` is declared as `undefined`, hoisted and then later assigned the value of a function expression. Hence it's `undefined` when it's called.

**An example of a function expression:**

```
(function (bar) {
    alert("foo" + bar);
}("bar"));
```

The above function will be immediately invoked as it's a function expression.

```
function (bar) {
    alert("foo" + bar);
}("bar"); // throws an error, can't call undefined
```

The above function will not be immediately invoked as it's a function declaration. Remember, declarations do not express (or return a value). So it's like trying to invoke `undefined` as a function.

**How does a function become an expression?**

If a function is used in the context where an expression is expected then it's treated as an expression. Otherwise it's treated as a declaration.

Expressions are expected when:

1. You're assigning a value to a variable (i.e. `identifier = expression`).
2. Inside parentheses (i.e. `( expression )`).
3. As an operand of an operator (i.e. `operator expression`).

Hence the following are all function expressions:

```
var foo = function () {};
(function () {});
~function () {};
```

Everything else is a function declaration. In short if your function is not preceded by anything, it's a declaration.

See this code: https://github.com/aaditmshah/codemirror-repl/blob/master/scripts/index.js#L94

The following function `isExpression` is used to test whether some arbitrary JavaScript code is an expression or not:

```
function isExpression(code) {
    if (/^\s*function\s/.test(code)) return false;

    try {
        Function("return " + code);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this clears any doubts in your mind.

In short:

1. A function expression **expresses** or returns a value (in this case a function). Hence it can be immediately invoked, but it can't be called before it appears in the program.
2. A function declaration is **hoisted**. Hence it can be called before it appears in the program. However since it doesn't express any value it can't be immediately invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when writing:

```
var foo = (function () {
          ...
}());
```

the use of the (superfluous but useful) grouping `()` is a common coding style to make it clear from very like first line that the right hand side is most likely an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE). However, in the second:

```
var foo = function () {
          ...
}();
```

it doesn't become apparent until you read the last line, which might be quite a few lines down. Until you reach the last line, you probably thought you were reading a plain assignment:

```
var foo = function () {
          ...
};
```

Note that the parenthesis can be used in a plain assignment too:

```
var foo = (function () {
          ...
});
```

but in that case they really are superfluous (and probably misleading due to the convention of using them for IIFEs).

See [An Important Pair of Parens](http://michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens).

Answer (score 1):

In the current context there's no difference for the interpreter. Usually preferable way of writing module is by wrapping the function with parentheses:

```
var person = (function () {
    // Private
    var name = "Robert";
    return {
        getName : function () {
            return name;
        }
    };
}());
```

That's because the syntax is cleaner and it's obviously that you want to invoke the function immediately after it is declared. One more reason is because:

```
(function () {
    //some stuff
}());
```

will work but

```
function () {
    //some stuff
}();
```

this wont.

By wrapping the function each time you use common codding style which is usually a good thing :-).