# What is the difference between these two Module pattern forms in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, closures, module-pattern, self-invoking-function

I've noticed that in different code samples on the web that there are two different closure forms -- but I haven't been able to find anything that identifies the difference (if any) between the two.

```
var module = (function() { ... })()
```

and

```
var module = (function() { ... }())
```

They both *seem* functionally equivalent in the sample below, but I seem to recall that at one time, the distinction was important (code worked with one form but not the other).

```
var sdk =(function(){
var privacy='illusion';
return (
    { 
        getPrivacy: function(){return privacy;}
    });
})()

console.log(sdk.getPrivacy());
```

seems to be identical to that the code fragment where the next-to-last line is replaced with `}())`

The same also seems to be true if I pass in a Module object to associate the public properties/methods to:

```
var sdk =(function($){
  var privacy='illusion';
  $.getPrivacy = function() { return privacy;}
  return($);
})(sdk=sdk||{})

console.log(sdk.getPrivacy());
```

or its counterpart form ending in `}(sdk=sdk||{}))`

Comment: You can use cleaner version of IIFE: `var module = function() { ... }()`. You don't need extra braces in this case.

Comment: `return (¶ {` - the horror.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023560/what-is-the-difference-between-two-declarations-of-module-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the previous questions :)  I was struggling for the right search terms.